# CRUD help laravel 5.8 user

Tags: php, laravel

its my firstime using laravel, now i at the auth, i make a user view and controller for add new user trough view its alrd solved and bcrypt password 
but every time i update through view, this password changed to str in database

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $user = new \App\User;
    $user->name = $request->name;
    $user->role = $request->role;
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->password = bcrypt('$request->password');
    $user->remember_token = str_random(60);
    $user->save();

    return redirect('/user')->with('success','Success data update');
}

            public function update(Request $request,$id)
         {
    $user = \App\User::find($id);
    $user->update($request->all());
    return redirect('/user')->with('succses','Succsess data update');
}
```

this is my create controller and update in same UserController.php

Comment: Try   `bcrypt($request->password);` without quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't put a variable between single quotes. It'll interpret it [always a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216).

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $user = new \App\User;
    $user->name = $request->name;
    $user->role = $request->role;
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
    $user->remember_token = str_random(60);
    $user->save();

    return redirect('/user')->with('success','Success data update');
}
```